# how to assign google chart image to hidden field in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, itext

im trying to print a google chart using textsharp. The only step I don't know how to perform is how to set the value using jquery on the web client side and be able to read it from code behind. Does anybody know how to do this?

I have an asp button that performs a client click and a server click:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnPDF" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="~/images/acroread.png" OnClick="btnPDF_Click" OnClientClick="return ExportToPDF(this)" ToolTip="Download PDF" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

This is the on client click event to set to the hidden field the image value from the chart:

```
$("[id*=btnExport]").click(function () {
$("input[name=chart_data]").val(div_chart.getImageURI());
});
```

This is how I am trying to get the hiddenfield value on c# codebehind (but keeps on getting null values):

```
string base64 = Request.Form["chart_data";
```

Answer (score 0):

typo in the `base64` assignment?

**S**tring base64 = Request.Form["chart_data"**]**;

Comment: well im not getting any data on there, but its supposed to be of type string. im always getting NULL